# How do I check if specific dependency is installed using yarn?

Tags: command-line, yarnpkg

Is there a way to check from `Terminal` if specific dependency (For example: `Lodash`) is installed in project or not using `Yarn`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the command `yarn list [--depth] [--pattern]`.

For your example it would look like this: `yarn list --pattern lodash`.
In this case it will not only look at dependencies specified in your package.json but in the whole dependency tree. So if you only want to check top-level dependencies you can add the flag `--depth=0`.

Details:
https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/list/

Comment: This correct of Yarn 1, `list` was removed in Yarn 2.

Comment: For Yarn 2 we can use yarn _info_ https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/info